# How can humans eventually become like Thor?

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution

So in the Marvel universe, Thor and other Asgardians are not Gods. They are simply *very* advanced human-like beings that have used [science and tech](http://s3.amazonaws.com/oratv/assets/prod/asset/224039-magic%20science-0.png) to become harder, better, faster, stronger.

Thor lives about 5000 years longer than us and is physically super-superior in every way. His skin, bones, everything seems Superman-esque. But he is, as Odin so emphatically puts it, [*not* a God](https://lovelace-media.imgix.net/uploads/141/ea22d920-41c8-0132-4129-0ebc4eccb42f.jpg?w=740&h=554&fit=crop&crop=faces&auto=format&q=70). He is born, he lives, and eventually he dies, just like humans.

**How might human anatomy and/or biotechnology progress and evolve to make us similar to Thor?**

Comment: They're aliens, not advanced humans. And in what way is the MCU anatomy not correct?

Comment: @Mormacil Duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

1. People could invent some super steroid that negates the effects/production of [myostatin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myostatin) and results in uninhibited muscle growth.  Bone strength would also need to be enhanced or the muscles would tear the bones apart
2. Our nerves can be enhanced also with some "steroid" for the brain, allowing for super reflexes and combat skills
3. Sexual Selection.  Over hundreds or even thousands of years, people could favor marrying (and reproducing with) people who are naturally big and buff.  Eventually, everyone will become today's standard of big and buff, and the standards will be set even higher.  (Repeat step 3 a few times and Dwayne Johnson will look scrawny.)
4. Life extensions are becoming a thing with cloning and what not.  If there were a way to transfer the contents of your brain to a clone of you (like hard drives) that's one way you could "live" forever.
5. Alaskan Wood Frogs (pls google it hyperlinking takes too long) freeze fully in the winter and come back like nothing ever happened in the spring.  If humans could do that with some injected [cyroprotectants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoprotectant) (you're welcome) that aren't toxic, we could freeze and come back possibly centuries later, maybe even millennia.
6. We could hit the gym and never come out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the Marvel universe, so I am basing the following on the information given in your question.

> Physically super-superior in every way

seems not too unlikely. If you compare an average human to a top athlete like [Ashton Eaton](https://www.google.no/search?q=ashton+eaton+body&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqvbvU4J7TAhUED5oKHZ-NBscQsAQIJQ&biw=1600&bih=681), the differences are striking. Hence, I would argue that most of what is needed to become "harder, better, faster, stronger" is already embedded in the human genetic code.

How do you get all humans to become more like that? Well, only those people mostly resembling Thors anatomy are allowed to reproduce: Forced selection of partners based on individual genetics will help to evolve super humans over time.

> live about 5000 years longer than us

This seems to me the more difficult part. [Negligibly senescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_senescence) humans are a dream of distant future. However, you might want to read up on the wikipedia article about [research strategies to neglect age-related damage to human tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategies_for_Engineered_Negligible_Senescence). From the article, you see that DNA mutations, junk protein, cell loss, loss of cell division capability and changes in cell linking protein all contribute to ageing in humans. Cancer and degenerative diseases are common consequences.

Summary: In my opinion, the **human anatomy** is already quite close to that of Thor and the way to get there is theoretically known. However, to reach the desired **age**, several profound advances in different fields of medicine and biotechnology that are currently far from reality, have to be achieved.